SQL Server DB has "dbo" user associated with different login name
Under the database is a user named "dbo", but it's associated with a "Login name" of a regular user of the database ("AppUser"). I'm guessing this was caused somehow during the migration of the database to a new server host.
Any attempts to fix this are met with "cannot alter the user 'dbo'", "cannot grant, deny or revoke permissions", or similar errors. Further, the Properties panel for that user has both the User and Login Name fields disabled.
The applications accessing this DB connect as AppUser, but I can't create that user because "that user is associated with a login name that is already in use". I've tried adding my own user to other roles but can't seem to get past the errors.
Any thoughts?

Seems like the LOGIN AppUser owns the database, so therefore dbo is mapped to that LOGIN. You'll need to change the owner of the database.

If, however, the application is meant to have full access to the database, is it an issue that it owns the database?

You were spot on. The DB was owned by AppUser.
I've now got the ownership changed to "sa", but I'm not finding a way to change dbo to map to the new owner (or anything else for that matter, as those fields are still disabled).

You don't the owner is mapped to dbo.
